# Searching in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search, file-search

I have lost one HTML folder in my Windows 7.

Is there a way I can search all CSS files in my m/c between Jan 1 -  Jan 20 2017?

I also have an external hard disk, can this search be extended there too?

Answer (score 0):

To search for all CSS files modified between Jan 1 - Jan 20 2017 enter the following in the search box:

```
datemodified: ‎1/‎1/‎2017..1/20/2017 *.css
```

And yes, you can search  in your external hard disk using the same query.

Comment: I have installed the programme, but could not find the search box in the programme. Can you Please help me?

Comment: What program? My solution doesn't require any installation. The search box I'm talking about is in the Explorer. You can usually find it at the top right.

Comment: Initially you told me to install Total Commander?

Comment: Is this syntax or command correct → datemodified: ‎1/‎1/‎2017..1/20/2017 *.png or datemodified: ‎1/‎1/‎2017..1/20/2017 *.css ?

Comment: I didn't recommend total commander. I think the person who recommended that deleted his answer.

Comment: Use *.css since you want to search for CSS files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52265/discussion-between-champion-and-kidus).